# Не статистический метод может вызываться как статистический

Tags: php

```
<?php
/**
* PHP 7.0.8 (cli)
*/
namespace Bugs;

class Bug
{
    public function non_static_method()
    {
        echo "Как это работает?";
    }
}

// Вызываем как статистический метод
Bug::non_static_method();
```

Comment: и? в чем вопрос? до php7 - это вполне себе поведение...... в php7 - это уже deprecated. Называется: читайте доки

Comment: Хм... А что такое стати***сти***ческий метод? Это как-то связано со статистикой? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот криво в PHP сделано разделение на статические и нестатические методы. Изначально в PHP4 статических методов не было, затем их добавили в PHP5 и ради обратной совместимости при этом сначала предупреждений вообще не было, затем стало генерироваться предупреждение всего лишь `E_STRICT`.

Поэтому - проверьте свой `error_reporting` и `display_errors`, вы не видите эти предупреждения языка. Ремарка для музейных версий, E_ALL не включал в себя E_STRICT до PHP 5.4.0 и должен был быть указан явно.

Хорошую ошибку поймаете, если попробуете к `$this` обратиться из такого метода, сразу Fatal error.

Comment: про ошибку в конце - такое поведение в целом свойственно не только PHP, но и множеству других ООП-языков. `Метод` обычно представляет с собой пару `АдресДанных-Адрес кода`, где адрес данных - это ссылка на память занимаемую объектом. Адрес кода - ссылка на точку входа в метод. Последнее привязано к самому классу (VMT), а не к конкретному объекту, так что последнее имеет место быть с тех пор как вы описываете сам класс. И пока код не обратится по `АдресуДанных` (`this` или `self`) с нужным смещением к полям (который без ) и не получит эксепшен то такой код будет работать везде.